# Reading hex to double-precision float python

Tags: python, hex

I am trying to `unpack` a hex string to a double in Python. When I try to unpack the following:

```
unpack('d', "4081637ef7d0424a");
```

I get the following error:

> struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8

This doesn't make very much sense to me because a double is 8 bytes long, and

2 character **=** 1 hex value **=** 1 byte

So in essence, a double of 8 bytes long would be a 16 character hex string.

Comment: The "string" expected by `struct.unpack` isn't a hex string, it's the raw bytes. In Python3, it would be `bytes`, not `str`. Use `bytearray.fromhex` or just `str.decode`, see Sven Marnach's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to convert the hex digits to a binary string first:

```
struct.unpack('d', "4081637ef7d0424a".decode("hex"))
```

or

```
struct.unpack('d', binascii.unhexlify("4081637ef7d0424a"))
```

The latter version works in both Python 2 and 3, the former only in Python 2

Comment: @L3viathan `binascii` does not require a third-party library.  It's part of Python's standard library, and on CPython it's even compiled into the interpreter, so it's alrleady imported upon interpreter start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = "\x40\x81\x63\x7e\xf7\xd0\x42\x4a"
unpack('d', a);
```